# I cannot get my fancybox 2 to work

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

My Fancybox images keep opening up in a new window and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong

website : http://www.benjarosz.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including javascript as css in this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

also include jQuery **before** any JQuery plugins like fancybox.

Comment: This was the issue! Thanks!